# How to return to today extension from app

Tags: ios, swift, today-extension

When the user taps the today extension it opens the app where they can modify its settings. But when the app is exited, the user is returned to the home screen. Is there any way I return focus to the today extension so the user can view the changes immediately? Or is this just not possible in iOS?

Comment: not possible ...........

Comment: yeah that's what I thought...

Answer (score -1):

I recommend making a button to go to the app. Or add transition functionality after applying settings.

like this

```
 var instagramHooks = "instagram://user?username=johndoe"
var instagramUrl = NSURL(string: instagramHooks)
if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(instagramUrl!)
{  
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(instagramUrl!)

 } else {
    //redirect to safari because the user doesn't have Instagram
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "http://instagram.com/")!)
}
```

User can click on the top left button to return if the application has been opened from another application. You can update the data on his return.

Comment: I have controls in the extension to customize it directly, but one of the options requires a text input, which is not available in the today extensions. But even if I added my own button to go to the app, that wouldn't solve the problem of returning from it

Comment: You can pass the values ​​and screen index to open in the scheme.

Comment: @O.Shulzhenko this can be used to open the app from an extension. The opposite is desired, but is not possible. Today extensions cannot be opened by a URL scheme